# Playwright how to wait for couple of requests?

Tags: networking, playwright

I have a very slow web site which loads couple of requests I'd like to wait for.
Here is an example of my code:

```
 await page.waitForRequest("/api/data/pagesTree1");
 await page.waitForRequest("/api/data/pagesTree2");
 await page.waitForRequest("/api/data/pagesTree3");
```

But happens next:
for example pagesTree1 is going, test waits for it, but pagesTree2 and 3 are already here, when second waitForRequest starts, it fails, because the request has arrived already, how can I handle this situation ?

Can I do something like:

```
await page.waitForRequest(["request1", "request2", ...]);
```

I mean waiting all of them at the same time.
Or there are other better approaches ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, I can do next:

```
await Promise.all([
            page.waitForResponse(resp => resp.url().includes('/api/data/pagesTree1') && resp.status() === 200),
            page.waitForResponse(resp => resp.url().includes('/api/pagesTree2') && resp.status() === 200),
            page.waitForResponse(resp => resp.url().includes('/api/pagesTree3') && resp.status() === 200),
        ]);
```